# How to transfer gold between my characters?

Tags: neverwinter

Is it possible to transfer gold from one of my characters to another one of my characters without getting a third person? If so, please explain.

Answer (score 5):

It is, now.

You can now deposit gold into your bank, scroll down to the bottom of your bank interface to see.

*Screenshot will follow when I get home*

Comment: No problem. If this worked, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Will do once i try it later today